# Package in launchpad but apt-get says no installation candidate found

Tags: apt, package-management, launchpad

I am trying to install liblcms1-dev on Ubuntu 15.04. I can see the package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/liblcms1-dev) on Launchpad. But when I run `apt-get install liblcms1-dev` I get:

```
E: Package 'liblcms1-dev' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at one of the [binary](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/i386/liblcms1-dev/1.19.dfsg-1.2ubuntu5) packages you'll notice their "**deleted**" status.

It seems that `lcms1` is deprecated and that migration to `lcms2` has started on several debian packages. That's why `liblcms1-dev` is not available in ubuntu repositories as of 15.04.

Source: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/12/msg00570.html

Comment: You can try downloading the `.deb` file from the same link and install it manually. Not sure if it'll work, but worth a try!